# Upload files to different virtual directory

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2008, iis

I have two web application hosted on different server.For eg. one is main application and the other one is branch application.
In branch application, user will upload their files but we want to keep all uploaded files in main application virtual directory.

So that we put the main application virtual directory path while we upload the files.But We got error message like "Invalid Directory" and can't upload.
Is there any way to upload files from one application to another directly? We are using normal html upload control in asp.net and visual studio 2008.

```
Code Sample : 
main application virtual directory "http://10.10.10.1/mainapp/uploadedfiles/" 
branch application virtual directory "http://10.10.10.2/branchapp/"

HttpPostedFile postedFile;
string saveFile = Path.Combine("http://10.10.10.1/mainapp/uploadedfiles/", "File1.pdf");
postedFile.SaveAs(saveFile);
```

Please guide me the right way and I really appreciated it.

Thanks.

Best Regards,

Chong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think u can share the directory and ensure both the Apps can access it, because the two apps are in different servers, the directory path maybe just like : \serverA\Files\, and the url of this directory is : http://localhost/files. u can save files to other servers by a relative path if u have the permission.

Answer (score 2):

In the FileUpload control, the FileUpload.SaveAs(path) method takes a physical path, not a virtual path.  So if you have a virtual path, you will need to use the Server.MapPath method to convert it to a physical path.  Using your example, you might want to change the last line of your code to:

postedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(saveFile))

Also, you will need to make sure that the account that ASP.Net is running under has ACL write permissions on the physical directory.